# Parametrize intersection of $z = \sin(x) + \sin(y)$ and $\frac{(x + 5)^2}{9} + \frac{(y − 1)^2}{16} = 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametrization

> Parametrize the intersection of the wave surface $z = \sin(x) + \sin(y)$
>   with the elliptic cylinder
>   $$\frac{(x + 5)^2}{9} + \frac{(y − 1)^2}{16} = 1$$

I'm thinking I can start with defining the second function in terms of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(y)$, but this is difficult for me. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE! Please take a look at this guide on how to use MathJax and consider typesetting your post with it, so that it's more readable. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The well-known parametrization for the ellipse $\dfrac{(x + 5)^2}{9} + \dfrac{(y − 1)^2}{16} = 1$ is 
\begin{cases}
x=-5+3\cos t,\\
y=1+4\sin t.
\end{cases}
so 
$z = \sin(-5+3\cos t) + \sin(1+4\sin t)$ shows the parametrization
$$\left(-5+3\cos t, 1+4\sin t, \sin(-5+3\cos t) + \sin(1+4\sin t)\right)$$
which hasn't a nice simplification (I think)!